# header in reportViewer

Tags: c#, header, reportviewer

I use VS2010 and I want to put a header (3-4 text lines) only on the first page and a  footer on the last page( also 3-4 text line).
Can anyone help me?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the visibility property on your label and add a condition that will show it only on the first page. I do not know the exact syntax but you can use the expression builder to create it.

EDIT : Just some thing to look out for, the visiblity property is reversed than usual. The real name is 'Hidden', so true will hide your control and false will show it.

Comment: Thanks! i want to know if it is possible to add a label for a textbox in the header and if it is possible to fill it dynamically